# WordPress functions.php custom code - I don't see error, but no render of content on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, ads

I really need help with this code, because can't figure out why isn't working and even does not have syntax error, content is not rendered on frontend, at all.

I created quiz blocks with questions and answers. Now I want to show mixed types of ads after certain number of questions. Sample code below:

```
add_filter('render_block_buzzeditor/personality-question', 'add_question_ad_place', 10, 2);
add_filter('render_block_buzzeditor/trivia-question', 'add_question_ad_place', 10, 2);

global $question_count;
$question_count = 1;
function add_question_ad_place($block_content, $block)
{
// only after the 2nd question
if($question_count === 2) {
$block_content .= 'ad code after 2';
}

if($question_count === 4) {
$block_content .= 'ad code after 4';
}

if($question_count === 6) {
$block_content .= 'ad code after 6';
}

$question_count++;

return $block_content;
}​
```

Idea is to count question blocks, and after certain number of blocks (2,4,6 in this case) place ads code and have ad after 2nd, 4th and 6th question.

No PHP errors, but just does not render content on frontend. What am I missing here? Thanx, guys.

Comment: In your function `add_question_ad_place`, place a `die("here");` to see if it is even called

Comment: Never worked with die() - where to place it? Sorry, I know it is maybe stupid question, but never worked with...sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just incrementing `$question_count` in local scope, to fix add

```
global $question_count;
```

As the first line of your function `add_question_ad_place`

Like so

```
add_filter('render_block_buzzeditor/personality-question', 'add_question_ad_place', 10, 2);
add_filter('render_block_buzzeditor/trivia-question', 'add_question_ad_place', 10, 2);

$question_count = 1;
function add_question_ad_place($block_content, $block)
{
global $question_count;
// only after the 2nd question
if($question_count === 2) {
$block_content .= 'ad code after 2';
}

if($question_count === 4) {
$block_content .= 'ad code after 4';
}

if($question_count === 6) {
$block_content .= 'ad code after 6';
}

$question_count++;

return $block_content;
}​
```

Comment: Believe or not - just beforer your answer I added the same and - NOTHING! I was so happy, thinking Oh, I forget about this, but noo. It does not work, will edit code in question

Comment: You need to add `global $question_count;` within the function, see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you man, you are awesome, will check your answer as correct. One quick question - if I want to add third ad, which will repeat till the end of quiz, do you have any suggestion how to do that within this code? Can I use ">=" instead of === in that case?

Comment: Yes you can do `if($question_count >= 8)` or whatever number